# like to include with parameters in asp classic

Tags: asp-classic, include, global-variables

Is it possible to do an include by passing parameters to a url?

Example: `<- # include file = "fac.asp ?idfac = 5" ->`

One way to solve the problem would be to make an iframe to this page and access a global variable that is defined in it, is it possible?

Comment: no it is not possible but you have access to the querystring in the included file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% idfac=5 %>
<- # include file = "fac.asp" ->
```

Answer (score 0):

set cookie idfac=5

then call in fac.asp and again set cookie idfac=0 in the end of fac.asp